# Qual a origem da expressão "ficar a ver navios"?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica, ditado-popular

Entendo a expressão perfeitamente, significa não receber ou conseguir algo que esperava. Mas porque o sujeito "vê navios"?

Comment: Sempre interpretei como sendo uma pessoa que perdeu o navio, então, ficou a ver navios indo embora.

Answer (score 3):

Há mais de uma explicação ([CiberDúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ficar-a-ver-navios/15080)). Eis algumas:

1. Em 1578, o rei de Portugal, Dom Sebastião, morreu em batalha, sendo seu corpo nunca encontrado. Assim, houve a anexação de Portugal à Espanha, de 1580 a 1640. O povo português sonhava com a volta do monarca; por isso, com frequência, visitavam o Alto de Santa Catarina, em Lisboa, e ficavam observando o mar, à espera do retorno de Dom Sebastião. Como o rei não voltou, o povo “ficou a ver navios”.
2. Alusão aos armadores portugueses que nos séculos das conquistas ficavam no alto de Santa Catarina, em Lisboa, esperando as caravelas que vinham das Índias, da África ou do Brasil. Indica ainda a hipótese de certo milionário portuense que, da Torre da Marca, viu afundarem-se todos os navios da sua frota, por mor de violento temporal.
3. Quando os franceses dominaram Portugal, diz-se que os homens a que poderei chamar da resistência iam para o alto de Santa Catarina, em Lisboa, a ver os navios que trouxessem o Desejado. E da vanidade da espera haverá nascido a expressão ficar a ver navios.

De qualquer modo, parece que vem da espera por algo que nunca chegou nem chegará.